# Wives of Shem, Cham, Yafes

Tags: tanach, parashat-noach

If everyone in the world was so corrupt that the world needed to be destroyed and rebuilt, where did Shem, Cham, and Yafes find women to marry?
Do we know their names?

Comment: There's nothing brough outright in the midrashim but apparently in (the non-canonized) Book of Jubilees it names them as Tzedektelebab, wife of Shem; Na'eltama'uk, wife of Cham; and Adataneses, wife of Yafes. Also related in Legend of the Jews - https://www.sefaria.org/Legends_of_the_Jews.1.4.81?ven=The_Legends_of_the_Jews_by_Louis_Ginzberg_[1909]&lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en